# Unable to crop mask from original image

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin

I'm trying to remove the background from an image. For that, I'm using TensorFlow which provides me mask of an object. After that, I'm cropping the mask from the image but the result is not as good as I wanted.

Using `TensorFlow` for **masking**:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/android
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/segmentation/overview

**Cropping** mask from the image.

```
 fun bitmapDstIn(mask: Bitmap?, original: Bitmap?): Bitmap? {
        return try {
            val result =
                original?.let { Bitmap.createBitmap(it.width, it.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) }
            val mCanvas = result?.let { Canvas(it) }
            val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
            paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
            mask?.let { mCanvas?.drawBitmap(it, 0f, 0f, null) }
            original?.let { mCanvas?.drawBitmap(it, 0f, 0f, paint) }
            paint.xfermode = null
            result
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.message.toString())
            original
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cropping the mask from an original bitmap. I'm SRC_OVER the result bitmap twice which hides the **transparency** issue.

```
fun creatingMasking(original: Bitmap?, mask: Bitmap?): Bitmap? {
            return try {
                var result: Bitmap? =
                    mask?.let { original?.let { it1 -> croppingMaskFromOriginal(it, it1) } }
                val final = result
                result = result?.let { overlay(it, it) }
                result = result?.let { final?.let { it1 -> overlay(it, it1) } }
                result
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                original
            } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
                original
            }
        }


        private fun croppingMaskFromOriginal(base: Bitmap, blend1: Bitmap): Bitmap {
            return try {
                val result: Bitmap =
                    base.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
                val blend = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(blend1, base.width, base.height, false)
                val p = Paint()
                p.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                p.shader = BitmapShader(blend, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
                p.alpha = 255
                val c = Canvas()
                c.setBitmap(result)
                c.drawBitmap(base, 0f, 0f, null)
                c.drawRect(0f, 0f, base.width.toFloat(), base.height.toFloat(), p)
                result
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                base
            } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
                base
            }
        }

        private fun overlay(base: Bitmap, blend1: Bitmap): Bitmap {
            return try {
                val result: Bitmap =
                    base.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
                val blend = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(blend1, base.width, base.height, false)
                val p = Paint()
                p.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)
                p.shader = BitmapShader(blend, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
                val c = Canvas()
                c.setBitmap(result)
                c.drawBitmap(base, 0f, 0f, null)
                c.drawRect(0f, 0f, base.width.toFloat(), base.height.toFloat(), p)
                result
            } catch (e: Exception) {

                base
            } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
                base
            }
        }
```